# How to invoke Linux shell and set PATH to it?

Tags: java, linux, shell, path

I want to open the default / or xterm (any Shell) in LINUX , I did this with ubuntu 12.xx,
I could invoke the xterm shell, but when I want to set the path to it, it says :
Error: could not exec /"path" : No privileges
how can I set a path to the xterm or any shell that I called  in JAVA ??

```
else  {
            String path = getCurrentFolderName().toString();
            //Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();

            String[] shellcom = {"xterm",  path };
            //r.exec(shellcom).waitFor();
            Process p ;
            ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder();
            //builder.directory(new File(path));
            builder = new Process Builder(shellcom);                
            p = builder.start();

              }
    }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the directory *after* you have created the `ProcessBuilder`. Not before.

```
        String[] shellcom = {"xterm"};
        Process p ;
        //builder.directory(new File(path));        // not here.
        builder = new ProcessBuilder(shellcom);                
        builder.directory(new File(path));          // here.
        p = builder.start();
```

Also notice that you shouldn't add the path to the array of strings `shellcom`. If you do that the path is passed to xterm as a parameter, and xterm will assume it's a program that should be executed, resulting in the error `xterm: Could not exec /your/path/here: Permission denied`.

Comment: ok I just did this , but again it says : Could not exec /"path" : No privileges ..?

Comment: Who says `Could not exec /"path"`? Is your code exactly like in my post?

Comment: oops , I didnt see the whole thing ;) now it works, thanks a lot ! :P

Comment: just one more question.... do you know if this works also with other LINUX or also MAC distributions ? I tested it with Ubuntu 12.xx but it would be pleasent if it also works with (most) of the other UNIX systems... problem is probably if there is always an xterm shell or if there is at all any default shell that you could apply / call in every Unix system... probably not

Comment: It will work on every system that has a GUI and `xterm` installed: it will not work if the program is running in a text console, or on systems that don't have `xterm`. For example newer versions of OS X don't have it. Also some Linux distributions don't come with `xterm` by default but it can be installed.

Comment: Since you're new here: if you find an answer useful you can mark it as "accepted", this let's other users know that the question already has an answer and also rewards the asker and answerer with points http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: ok I will do that, but I still have some questions : Do you know a better method to invoke the default shell or some shell on the UNIX systems and then set the paths to it ? maybe other than xterm?so that it works on other UNIX systems as well?

Comment: There is no portable concept of "default terminal emulator" (the word "shell" means something else). In the worst case the program can be running as a daemon and no console or window system is available, so you can't really pop up any window of any kind. If you assume that the program is running on Unix in an environment that has a window system available, running `xterm` is a fairly safe choice. On OS X you should open `Terminal.app` instead.

Comment: ok well, instead of xterm, I entered gnome-terminal and it worked as well, is that ok  or is xterm the better option?

Comment: is there maybe any way to let the system "choose" which terminal it applies ? In case there is one option not present in the system, then it chooses another program? maybe like                            String[] shellcom = {"gnome-terminal", " || xterm"};  but || probably doesnt work, is there any other way?

Comment: You can use shell syntax if you start a shell: `{"bash", "-c", "gnome-terminal || xterm"}`. On distros based on Debian the preferred terminal emulator can be run with `x-terminal-emulator`